# To use Django FileField or FilePathField?

Tags: django

I'm a bit confused about which field to use. What I need is just a Field that will hold a file (audio and/or another one for an image)

The FileField seems to be specifically for uploading and I think it is a bit of overkill for what I need, I also don't like how it will automatically upload and rename the files to a unique filename (file_FHjgh758.txt) everytime something is uploaded.

The problem I have with the FilePathField is that it seems to require an absolute path, which would obviously be different from dev to production, I got around this by adding this to the model...

```
import os

class Foo(models.Model):

    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    path = os.join(path, 'media')
    audio = models.FilePathField(path=path)
```

I have no idea if this is safe or proper, and there aren't many examples online or in the docs to draw from.

To be clear, I just want to have a field which I can point to a file (audio or image) somewhere in my system. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to refer to files that are already on your filesystem rather than user uploaded files, then `FilePathField` is the one that you want.

In this regard a few comments:

- **Don't** point to a path that is inside your app's source tree. That is not safe.
- You can use settings or environment variables to handle development vs. production paths, e.g., put a `FILE_PATH_FIELD_DIRECTORY` setting in your development/production settings files and refer to this setting from your app:

  ```
  from django.conf import settings

  class Foo(models.Model):
      audio = models.FilePathField(path=settings.FILE_PATH_FIELD_DIRECTORY)
  ```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this makes sense to me although I am stuck on how to call the file location from a template. If I call the url saved in the db it is something like '/home/../../' and the html tries to make it relative to the dev server which is incorrect. I think I am missing something obvious here

Comment: I think the issue is that `FilePathField` is meant more for files located on your server that are not accessible through the web server... if you want to public files then you are better off using `FileField` which has a `url` attribute and which will also save the files in an accessible place (in your `MEDIA_ROOT`). You can override the saving behaviour of the `FileField` to prevent the random suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, if I'm not mistaken I should also make an entry in the urls.py and a view to handle the requests coming into the /media folder? Is that correct or is that also dangerous?

Comment: Django cannot handle requests for static files and media - it expects you to configure your web server to do that - see [the extensive documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) on handling of static files. Your `urls.py` should only contain URLs for dynamic content generated by Django (except [in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)).

Comment: Where the settings are placed? In which file?