# Which field in Django model to choose for a file downloaded via API endpoint?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.2 LTS

I have a function that will download a file from endpoint

```
def download_as_file(url: str, auth=(), file_path="", attempts=2):
    """Downloads a URL content into a file (with large file support by streaming)

    :param url: URL to download
    :param auth: tuple containing credentials to access the url
    :param file_path: Local file name to contain the data downloaded
    :param attempts: Number of attempts
    :return: New file path. Empty string if the download failed
    """
    if not file_path:
        file_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.basename(url))
    logger.info(f"Downloading {url} content to {file_path}")
    url_sections = urlparse(url)
    if not url_sections.scheme:
        logger.debug("The given url is missing a scheme. Adding http scheme")
        url = f"https://{url}"
        logger.debug(f"New url: {url}")
    for attempt in range(1, attempts + 1):
        try:
            if attempt > 1:
                time.sleep(10)  # 10 seconds wait time between downloads
            with requests.get(url, auth=auth, stream=True) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                with open(file_path, "wb") as out_file:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):  # 1MB chunks
                        out_file.write(chunk)
                logger.info("Download finished successfully")
                return (response, file_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f"Attempt #{attempt} failed with error: {ex}")
    return None
```

I also intend to have a Django model to store metadata associated with that downloaded file.

```
class DownloadedFile(models.Model):
    # other fields but i skipped most of them here
    local_copy = models.FileField(upload_to="downloads/")
```

I know there's a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield) and a [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield)

my idea is to do something like in pseudocode:

```
# code that downloads the file and affix a timestamp as prefix for filename happens here.
response, downloaded_file_path_in_local_directory = download_as_file(url_of_file_to_download_from, auth_tuple)
# now to save the data into database
new_f = DownloadedFile()
new_f.field_1 = "abc"
new_f.local_copy = "I dont know what to put here because it depends whether i choose FileField or FilePathField"
new_f.save()
```

So what do I do at  the part where I am supposed to assign `local_copy`? and also should I use FileField or FilePathField?

### Update 1

Okay, I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33073537/80353

It suggests that if the file will be exposed to public users via media, then use FileField, else if it's an existing file, then use FilePathField.

Is that a fair criterion to decide?

### Update 2

Let me be clear. The files in this case are definitely files coming from (or files that my Django app will pull from) other systems not in control by me. They will not be files uploaded by human agents aka users.

Will they be served to public anonymous users of my Django app? That's not certain at this point. It's a maybe. Don't harangue me for this maybe. I have tried my best to force an answer from the customer, but right now, it's a maybe at best.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly and obvious choice to make:

This is what Django docs say about `FilePathField`

> A CharField **whose choices are limited to the filenames in a certain directory on the filesystem**. Has some special arguments, of which the first is required:

If you want to serve files on your server go for `FilePathField`.If, on the other hand, you want to **store files received from users**, then, go for the `FileField`.

**Update:**

As for storing the file, whether the file is coming from other users or machines: if you are using Django `ModelForms`, you can deal with your file as follows (assuming you are working with Django forms and not `DRF` serializers):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            form.save()  # Explaination below
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

When you issue `form.save()` your file in that form will be saved into your `MEDIA_ROOT`. You can define an alternative path for storage in your `FileField`.

You can postpone the decision for downloading the file later given that it's a separate issue. You are not forced to make the decision here or provision anything complicated in advance.

Comment: Ok, then to be preicese, I store files received from other systems or machines. I read 'users' as human agents

Comment: And assuming it's FileField how do I assign it? `new_f.local_copy = "I dont know what to put here"`

Comment: @KimStacks Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound blunt. I appreciate the effort you put into writing the answer. But I feel that my question is either not read properly, or I didn't explain myself well. My original question included a download function. The purpose is to emphaize that my Django app will call this function to download a file from another system into my Django app file directory. Given that's the case, why would I ever use a upload form? My subsequent update 2 highlighted, no human agents are involved. It's all my Django app taking the initiative to download a file from a url. Again, sorry if blunt